# openui5 googlemaps xmlview

Tags: sapui5

I am currently building an, where i need to add a maps option. I found the openui5-googlemaps option which fitted my needs. Currently i managed to get the marker to work in an xml view without any problems. However I want to add directions with waypoints similar to what you see here:
[DirectionsWithWaypoints](http://jasper07.secondphase.com.au/openui5-googlemaps/samples/directionstestwaypoints.html)

But i can't figure out how to build this into my XML view. I tried to add this via the controller to the view and just add the myMap element to the page. That did show the map, but it didn't show any directions, i looked at the binding and i had the correct binding.

If i added the myMap to the context of the HTML file instead, then it works.

[See the code here](http://pastebin.com/V1AbjkMT)

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one trick to finding out how to make something work in an XML view is via the SAPUI5 Diagnostics tool, it generates the xml for you

```
<ctrl><shift><alt> + S
```

opens the SAPUI5 Diagnostics tool, then 
  -> Control Tree -> Export -> XML

here is an example [using generated xmlview](http://jasper07.secondphase.com.au/openui5-googlemaps/samples/directionstestwaypointsview.html)